# homeomorphism between $B$ and $(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Q)\setminus A$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A = \{1\} \times \{0\} \times\Bbb Q$ and $B = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times\Bbb Q - (\{1\} \times \{0\} \times \mathbb{Q})$. How you show that $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: Your title asks for something different.

Comment: I feel sierpiniski theorem does the homoemorphism but I dont know how!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: It’s easy to show that $A$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$, so you’re done if you can show that $B$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$. Since $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Z$, it’s not hard to show that $B$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Q$. Then you need only show that $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Q$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$. A hint for that: if $$Q_n=\left(\sqrt2+n,\sqrt2+n+1\right)\cap\Bbb Q$$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$, then $\Bbb Q$ is the disjoint union of the sets $Q_n$.

**Added:** The argument suggested above is very elementary. If you already know Sierpiński’s characterization of the rationals as the unique countable metric space without isolated points, then of course it’s completely trivial to show that $A$ and $B$ are both homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I think that's more complicated than necessary, but I'd like to see the OP's attempt.

Comment: @dfeuer: There are shorter arguments if one has the necessary background, but I doubt that you’ll find a more elementary argument.

Comment: I think my answer leads to a simpler elementary argument.

Comment: I see what you mean now.

Comment: @dfeuer: It doesn’t: it’s essentially the same argument.